# scrape website traffic from semrush using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape website traffic from semrush.com.

my current code using BeautifulSoup is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, BeautifulStoneSoup
import urllib
import json

req = urllib.request.Request('https://www.semrush.com/info/burton.com', headers={'User-Agent':'Magic Browser'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
raw_data = response.read()
response.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_data)
```

I've been trying `data = soup.findAll("a", {"href":"/info/burton.com+(by+organic)"})` or `data = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"sem-report-counter"})` without much luck.

I can see the numbers on the webpage that I would like to get. Is there a way to pull this information off? I'm not seeing it in the html I pull.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can't scrape this page without a tool that can deal with dynamic content loaded in via `JavaScript` code. You'll need to use something like `selenium` in `headless` mode for this.

Comment: good to know, thanks @Dascienz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went the extra mile and set up a working example of how you can use `selenium` to scrape that page. Install `selenium` and try it out!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://www.semrush.com/info/burton.com' #your url
options = Options() #set up options
options.add_argument('--headless') #add --headless mode to options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/opt/ChromeDriver/chromedriver',
                      chrome_options=options)

#note: executable_path will depend on where your chromedriver.exe is located

driver.get(url) #get response
driver.implicitly_wait(1) #wait to load content
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath='//a[@href="/info/burton.com+(by+organic)"]') #grab that stuff you wanted?  

for e in elements: print(e.get_attribute('text').strip()) #print text fields

driver.quit() #close the driver when you're done
```

Output that I see in my terminal:

```
356K
6.5K
59.3K
$usd305K
Organic keywords
Organic
Top Organic Keywords
View full report
Organic Position Distribution
```

Comment: Wow, that is above and beyond. Thank you 1000 times. last question. If I wanted to run this on this one site many times, will it raise any issues?

Comment: The only issue is that you should be polite with your web-scraping. Identify your scraper by passing a dummy user-agent and limit your download speed by implementing a time delay between response requests. I can't guarantee you won't get banned if you have an extensive job to run though. If you haven't already, I'd look into the scrapy library for implementing more robust crawlers.

Comment: I'm assuming I add the `headers = {'User-Agent':dummy}` to the `driver.get`. What do I put for the dummy part of it? I'm new to web scraping.
Also, what is considered a polite speed limitation. Should I wait a minute, 5 10 between each time it calls the website?

Comment: Actually, I misspoke. You don't need to pass a header since selenium uses your browser (in this case chrome) to pass the request. Do watch that your request rate isn't invasive though. Happy scraping!

Comment: Thanks very much @Dascienz! I appreciate it.